# Is this acceptable notation for a "how to play" excerpt?

Tags: notation, lilypond

I have notated (via LilyPond) how I would like a turn to be played in my score.  Is this an acceptable way to notate this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chatted with my wife who has a masters in violin performance and she said music excerpts are notated with an asterisk (or some other obvious symbol) with the example shown at the bottom.  She showed me one of her pieces like this and I also found this in one of my double bass books (in the example below, "*)" is used):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your question is just "is it acceptable" then I'd say yes, but it can be improved.

- Those explanations usually go at the bottom.
- The example should use the same pitches as the actual music.

Comment: I chatted with my wife about this who has a masters in violin performance and she said the excerpt should go at the bottom as well.  She showed me music where an asterisk is used to show excerpts so I think that way may actually be the standard way to do it